# how to make a list of class in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a class

```
Class A{
  string a;
  int b;
  getters and setters of a and b;
}
```

I want to make a list of objects of class A. How is it possible in Java

I want to also set the values of a and b.

Comment: Illustrate the effect you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A a new A();
a.setA("aaa");
a.setB(4);

List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
aList.add(a);
 ///    .... 

String a;
int b;

for(A a: aList){
   a = a.getA();
   b = a.getB();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use arrays...

```
 A[] listOfA = new A[]{new A(), new A(), new A(), new A(), new A()};
 A[] anotherListOfA = new A[5];
 for (int index = 0; index < anotherListOfA.length; index++) {
      anotherListOfA[index] = new A();
 }
```

Check out [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details

You could use an implementation of `List`

```
 List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<>(5);
 for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      listOfA.add(new A());
 }
```

Check out [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Comment: hey, can you tell how to set values in the listOfA

Comment: The same way you set values normally.  You get a reference to the object and you set what every properties it has.  Take a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and [`List#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))

Answer (score 1):

```
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();

A anObj = new A();
anObj.setA(1);
anObj.setB(1);

aList.add(anObj);
```

Comment: and how will i set the values of a and b

Answer (score 1):

```
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
```

To set value

```
A a = new A();
a.setMethod("Hello World");
aList.add(a);
```

List out value

```
for(A aa : aList){
System.out.println(aa.getMethod());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new A();
a.setA("bbb");
a.setB(88);

List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
list.add(a);
/////.....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array of type A

```
List<A> myList = new ArrayList<A>();
```

then Creat an A object

```
A a = new A();
a.setA = stringA; // or whatever you want to set on the object
```

then add that object to the array

```
myList.add(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

List is just an interface. So you can not instantiate a `List`. You have to use classes that implements `List` interface. For example `ArrayList`.

You can try this out

```
      ArrayList <A> listOfA = new ArrayList<A>(intitalCapacity);
```